# Init State var coming from another view , swiftui

Tags: swiftui, init

Navigating from view A to view B, i m passing a var show . View A isn t visible anymore .

I need to have a @State var stateShow whose initial value is the same as value show passed to B from A .

How to do it without using onAppear ? Thanx

```
struct B : View {

    public var show:Bool
    
    @State private stateShow : Bool
    
    init (_ show : Bool){
        self.show = show
    }
    
}
```

Comment: maybe but not to my knowledge

Comment: `_stateShow = State(initialValue: show)`

Answer (score 0):

init (_ show : Bool){

```
    self.show = show
    _stateShow = State(initialValue: show)
}
```

Answer credited to vadian ,another similar question was asked with  a similar answer but slightly different conditions :